# Azure SQL optimize IN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to optimize the IN query on Azure SQL. This IN query has more than 50k records. With the optimization, I will use the INNER join. This is what I was trying

`SELECT incident_nbr from table_name as incidents INNER JOIN unnest(ARRAY['INC123456', 'INC0123456', 'INC432156']) as inc ON inc=incidents.incident_nbr;`

But looks this syntax is incorrect. DBeaver shows this error in the SQL script editor.

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:577)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:486)
```

Am I missing anything? TIA.

Comment: That doen't look like correct SQL Server syntax, what exactlly are you trying to do? SQL Server doesn't have arrays, maybe you want a Table Valued Parameter?

Comment: It doesn't work out in sql, UNNEST is not function of sql server, I think it is function of postgresql.

Comment: I am trying to create a temporary table from an array of strings and then use the INNER JOIN statement with the actual table.

Answer (score 1):

Is this going to be an sql statement generated on the fly?  Try this:

```
;WITH inc AS (
    SELECT ‘INC0123456’ AS col1
    UNION SELECT ‘INC432156’
)
SELECT incident_nbr 
FROM table_name as incidents 
INNER JOIN inc
ON incidents.incident_nbr = inc.col1;
```

With 50k rows, you might also want to try  inserting into an indexed temp table.

Comment: Thanks @Greg for this solution. I think this will work. I need to find a way to match bunch of INC strings.

Comment: This is one way, another option is to insert into temp table, add index if necessary and then join to your query

Comment: Thanks, @Greg, this approach worked. I'm inserting it into a temp table without any index and then later using MERGE query to either INSERT/UPDATE the record in the original table.